Marking Agent output as `HumanMessage` in LangChain
Why does the agent_node saves the LLM output as HumanMessage in this example?
from typing import List, Optional
from langchain.output_parsers.openai_functions import JsonOutputFunctionsParser
from langchain_core.prompts import ChatPromptTemplate, MessagesPlaceholder
from langchain_openai import ChatOpenAI

from langgraph.graph import END, StateGraph, START
from langchain_core.messages import HumanMessage, trim_messages

llm = ChatOpenAI(model="gpt-4o-mini")

trimmer = trim_messages(
    max_tokens=100000,
    strategy="last",
    token_counter=llm,
    include_system=True,
)


def agent_node(state, agent, name):
    result = agent.invoke(state)
    return {
        "messages": [HumanMessage(content=result["messages"][-1].content, name=name)]
    }


def create_team_supervisor(llm: ChatOpenAI, system_prompt, members) -> str:
    """An LLM-based router."""
    options = ["FINISH"] + members
    function_def = {
        "name": "route",
        "description": "Select the next role.",
        "parameters": {
            "title": "routeSchema",
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "next": {
                    "title": "Next",
                    "anyOf": [
                        {"enum": options},
                    ],
                },
            },
            "required": ["next"],
        },
    }
    prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_messages(
        [
            ("system", system_prompt),
            MessagesPlaceholder(variable_name="messages"),
            (
                "system",
                "Given the conversation above, who should act next?"
                " Or should we FINISH? Select one of: {options}",
            ),
        ]
    ).partial(options=str(options), team_members=", ".join(members))
    return (
        prompt
        | trimmer
        | llm.bind_functions(functions=[function_def], function_call="route")
        | JsonOutputFunctionsParser()
    )


Because you are converting it to HumanMessage in the return statement. If you want it to be AIMessage, just do the following as the return statement.
return {"messages" : result}

